# Hide irelavent Jobs from Spring Batch Admin

Tags: spring-batch-admin

I am using oracle DB which shares multiple application, I am using spring-batch-admin-manager:1.3.1.RELEASE to monitor the jobs which we have created.

How to filter or hide other application batches that appears in our admin application?

Answer (score 0):

If you have different jobs(that of another application too) sharing the same batch meta data tables, you could override `jobs.ftl` and `execution.ftl` to make sure that you only show the list of jobs that you intend to. Hope this helps.